# Как установить одинаковые расстояния между картинками с помощью флексов

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Как установить одинаковое расстояние между картинками с помощью флексов как показано на скрине

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brich Std';
  src: url('fonts/BirchStd.otf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Italic';
  src: url('fonts/Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background: url("img/background.png");
    margin: 0;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.main span{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header{
    margin-top: 35px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    width: 76%;
}

/*Search form*/
.search img{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    left: -3px;
}

.search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.search-form-input {
  width: 230px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 38px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Time New Roman, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search-form-btn {
  /* Позиционирование относительно <form> */
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px; /* 2px - размер border'а поля формы */
  top: 2px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;

  /* Просто тюнинг внешнего вида */
  color: #666;
  font-weight: bold;      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search span{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.search img{
    width: 90%;
}

/*End search form*/

/*joing*/

.join{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.join span{
    padding-right: 10px;
}
/* End join*/

/*Menu*/

.menu{
    display: flex;
}

.menu .logo{
    margin-top: -60px;
}

.menu .left, .right{
    margin-top: 37px;
}

/*Menu Left*/
.menu-left{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -105px;
}

.menu-left li{
    padding-left: 110px;
    margin-top: -63px;
    font-family: 'Brich Std';
    font-size: 19pt;
}

.menu-left ul{
    
}

.menu-left a:visited{
    color: #404040;
}

.menu-left a:hover{
    color: #b0353f;
}
/*End Menu Left*/

/*Menu Right*/
.menu-right{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.menu-right li{
    padding-left: 110px;
    margin-top: -63px;
    font-family: 'Brich Std';
    font-size: 19pt;
}

.menu-right ul{
    
}

.menu-right a:visited{
    color: #404040;
}

.menu-right a:hover{
    color: #b0353f;
}

/*End Menu Right*/
/*End Menu*/

/*Portfolio*/

.portfolio{
    margin-top: -55px;
}

.portfolio h1{
    color: #404040;
    font-size: 110pt;
    font-family: 'Brich Std';
    font-weight: 100;
}

.portfolio p{
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-family: 'Italic';
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -90px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.portfolio span{
    position: relative;
    left: 188px;
}

/*Button*/
.button1{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 450px;
}

a.button {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: 'Brich Std';
  font-size: 30pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .2em 0.7em calc(.1em + 1px);
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #af2330;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px #981e2a inset;
  transition: 0.2s;
} 
/*End Button*/
/*End Portfolio*/

/*Slider*/

.slide1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/*End Slider*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Design Group</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="search">
        <span>Search: </span> <form action="#" class="search-form">
            <input type="search" class="search-form-input" placeholder="" />
                <button type="submit" class="search-form-btn">
                    <!-- Сюда можно запихнуть любую картинку на свой вкус -->
                <img src="img/Search.png" alt="">
                </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="join">
        <span>Join Us: </span>
        <a href=""><img src="img/Facebook.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/Twitter.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/Wifi.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/Mail.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="left">
       <img src="img/Left.png" alt="">
        <ul class="menu-left">
            <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>About Us</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Our Services</li></a>
        </ul>
       </div>
        <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        <img src="img/Right.png" alt="">
        <ul class="menu-right">
            <a href=""><li>Portfolio</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
            <a href=""><li>Contact Us</li></a>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="portfolio">
        <h1>We Do More Than Just Websotes!</h1>
        <p>Mauris accumsan nulla vel diam. Sed in lacus ut enim adipiscing aliquet. Nulla venenatis.<br>
        <span>In pede mi, aliquet sit amet, euismod in,auctor ut, ligula.</span>
        </p>
        <div class="button1"><a href="#" class="button">See Our Portfolio</a></div>
    </div>

<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1">
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/0d04b61b194ff2fcd6c59c041dc9d057-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/4bdb0c76650288fd156e85daffa8935b-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/511326b5eb7e3a20479f5a3c51ea6321-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/897aacd0b42a3ccfcd6e5d6be0d54e29-full.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>    
   </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё проще, чем вы думаете...

[image]
       [image]
       [image]
       [image]

```css
.slide1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1">
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/0d04b61b194ff2fcd6c59c041dc9d057-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/4bdb0c76650288fd156e85daffa8935b-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/511326b5eb7e3a20479f5a3c51ea6321-full.png" alt=""></div>
       <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/897aacd0b42a3ccfcd6e5d6be0d54e29-full.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>    
   </div>
```

Comment: Блин и правда спасибо.

Comment: А с чем может быть связано что у меня на сайте нечего не изменилось?

Comment: @BraFik сказать сложно, кинь пример всего кода.

Comment: @Максим Буяков щас кину но не знаю поможет ли

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Я отредактировал код он там коряво получился когда его выполняешь но на сайте вроде бы норм выглядит

Comment: @МаксимБуяков  А всё решил проблему

Comment: @BraFik и в чём она заключалась?

Comment: @МаксимБуяков Я просто задал мейну дисплей флекс, и оно почему-то не работало в этом блоке, когда я вынес за мейн слайдер всё начало работать

Answer (score 3):

Нужно было задавать настройки родительскому элементу.(`display: flex` задается только один раз родителю).[Советую прочесть](http://css-live.ru/articles/vizualnoe-rukovodstvo-po-svojstvam-flexbox-iz-css3.html)

```css
.slide1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide1">
    <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/0d04b61b194ff2fcd6c59c041dc9d057-full.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/4bdb0c76650288fd156e85daffa8935b-full.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/511326b5eb7e3a20479f5a3c51ea6321-full.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="sl_slide"><img src="https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/29/897aacd0b42a3ccfcd6e5d6be0d54e29-full.png" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```